# Add a custom dictionary to manageable dictionaries?

Tags: iphone, ios, dictionary

Is it possible to add a custom dictionary to use for the "Define" feature on iOS? 
[image: List if manageable dictionaries]

For example, I want to add a dictionary of unix/linux commands so that in situations like this a definition is provided:

[image: Highlighting a word to be defined]
[image: No definition returned]

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer but with a question at the end.
First of all you need jail broken device or any other way to access system files.
On your browser press on some word and select 'define' then 'manage'
Install some other dictionary and then you need file system access to navigate to:
/var/mobile/Library/Assets/com_apple_MobileAsset_DictionaryServices_dictionary2

There you will see several folders, enter inside and then once again inside assetdata folder, there you will see name of the dictionary that you installed previously. Enter inside that folder and then inside 'contents'.
Basically this is the folder of the dictionary and all the data.

Now on your pc search on the net for OS X dictionary files (they will be in zip file) extract from that file only the files of 'contents' folder and replace the files on your mobile idevice.

I did it to add Hebrew language dictionary.

Comment: Dictionary.Appender does not work on ios8 :( and not found on AppStore.

Comment: Please use this area for answers only. If you'd like to ask a question, please post it as a new question. For more information on how Ask Different and the StackExchange Q&A format works please see our [FAQ](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq).

Answer (score 0):

If you can find the app called Dictionary.Appender it might be possible.

Comment: Are you referencing something in iOS code? I can't find an app in the app store under that name. Can you provide a link to what you're talking about?

Comment: It was once in the US app store but then disappeared for some reason.  Try a google search.